# Managing multiple domains in a rails application error: "NameError (uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000563d7bf62250>::Heroku):"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cross-domain, heroku-api

In my rails app, I'm trying to create a booking form external parties(`parks`) can point their customers to to make a booking for the respective park. The booking form works with the url/route with the subdomain *book*

```
https://book.myapp.com/en/parks/:park_id/park_availability
```

**Goal**

I would like substitute my domain (`myapp.com`) with the website of the `park`, such that I get

```
https://book.parkapp.com/en/park_availability
```

Unfortunately I get the error message(s)
upon creation park

```
NameError (uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000563d7bf62250>::Heroku):
```

when using an existing park

```
{park.website}'s server IP address could not be found.
```

**Outline attempted approach**

1. `Park` has a `website` column. In `routes.rb` I tried setting up the constraints and apply them on the `park_availability` action.
2. In the `Park` model I attempted to add the domain (`Park.website`) to my Heroku application, once the park is saved.
3. In my `Park controller` I try to find the `@park`, before the `park_availability` action.

**Code**

routes.rb

```
class CustomDomainConstraint
  # Implement the .matches? method and pass in the request object
  def self.matches? request
    matching_site?(request)
  end

  def self.matching_site? request
    # handle the case of the user's domain being either www. or a root domain with one query
    if request.subdomain == 'www'
      req = request.host[4..-1]
    else
      req = request.host
    end

    # first test if there exists a Site with a domain which matches the request,
    # if not, check the subdomain. If none are found, the the 'match' will not match anything
    Park.where(:website => req).any?
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :parks do
     match ':website/park_availability' =>  'parks#park_availability', on: :member, :constraints => CustomDomainConstraint, via: :all
end
end
```

park.rb

```
class Park < ApplicationRecord
  after_save do |park|
  heroku_environments = %w(production staging)
  if park.website && (heroku_environments.include? Rails.env)
    added = false
    heroku = Heroku::API.new(api_key: ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY'])
    heroku.get_domains(ENV['APP_NAME']).data[:body].each do |domain|
      added = true if domain['domain'] == park.website
    end

    unless added
      heroku.post_domain(ENV['APP_NAME'], park.website)
      heroku.post_domain(ENV['APP_NAME'], "www.#{park.website}")
    end
  end
end
```

parks_controller.rb

```
class ParksController < ApplicationController
before_action :find_park, only:[:park_availability]

def park_availability
  #working code...
end

private
def find_park
     # generalise away the potential www. or root variants of the domain name
    if request.subdomain == 'www'
      req = request.host[4..-1]
    else
      req = request.host
    end

    # test if there exists a Park with the requested domain,
    @park = Park.find_by(website: req)

    # if a matching site wasn't found, redirect the user to the www.<website>
    redirect_to :back
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get around error in question you can try writing classname as `::Heroku`, that will make ruby to look for it in correct scope.

But Heroku [legacy api](https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb) has been [disabled](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/1181), so you should use their [new platform-api](https://github.com/heroku/platform-api):

```rb
heroku = PlatformAPI.connect(ENV['HEROKU_API_KEY']) # note that you may also have to use a new key
domains = heroku.domain.list(ENV['APP_NAME'])
...
heroku.domain.create(ENV['APP_NAME'], ...)
```

also to check for domain presence you can use [`domain.info`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-reference#domain-info) api method instead of fetching all domains that are not needed.

Keep in mind that callbacks are not the best place to make any external calls: if the api call fails for some reason (temporary network problems, api outage, server restart, etc) - whole transaction will be rolled back, item will not be saved and you can *loose data*. Better way is to enqueue a background job there, which will handle domains later, can retry if needed and so on.

Comment: Thank you Fasfed, you were right about the legacy api part so I updated it. Nevertheless, I still get the same error message.

Comment: @techquestion have you tried `::PlatformAPI`? Also try stopping spring, if you use it, and cleaning bootsnap cache (delete bootsnap-* in tmp/cache)